# ML Expression, help line by line

Tags: expression, ml

```
val y=2;
fun f(x) = x*y;
fun g(h) = let val y=5 in 3+h(y) end;
let val y=3 in g(f) end;
```

I'm looking for a line by line explanation. I'm new to ML and trying to decipher some online code. Also, a description of the "let/in" commands would be very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm more familiar with ocaml but it all looks the same to me.

```
val y=2;
fun f(x) = x*y;
```

The first two lines bind variables `y` and `f`.  `y` to an integer `2` and `f` to a function which takes an integer `x` and multiplies it by what's bound to `y`, `2`.  So you can think of the function `f` takes some integer and multiplies it by `2`.  (`f(x) = x*2`)

```
fun g(h) = let val y=5
           in
               3+h(y)
           end;
```

The next line defines a function `g` which takes some `h` (which turns out to be a function which takes an integer and returns an integer) and does the following:

1. Binds the integer `5` to a temporary variable `y`.

   - You can think of the `let`/`in`/`end` syntax as a way to declare a temporary variable which could be used in the expression following `in`.  `end` just ends the expression.  (this is in contrast to ocaml where `end` is omitted)
2. Returns the sum of `3` plus the function `h` applying the argument `y`, or `5`.

At a high level, the function `g` takes some function, applies `5` to that function and adds `3` to the result.  (`g(h) = 3+h(5)`)

At this point, three variables are bound in the environment: `y = 2`, `f = function` and `g = function`.

```
let val y=3
in
    g(f)
end;
```

Now `3` is bound to a temporary variable `y` and calls function `g` with the function `f` as the argument.  You need to remember that when a function is defined, it keeps it's environment along with it so the temporary binding of `y` here has no affect on the functions `g` and `f`.  Their behavior does not change.

`g` (`g(h) = 3+h(5)`), is called with argument `f` (`f(x) = x*2`).  Performing the substitutions for parameter `h`, `g` becomes `3+((5)*2)` which evaluates to `13`.

I hope this is clear to you.